# AdjacencyList of DirectedEdges in Graph ignore edge direction

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I have a simple tree graph with directed edges:

```
In: AdjacencyList[Graph[{a -> b, a -> c, b -> d, b -> e}], b]
Out: {a, d, e}
```

I wonder how I can select only the outgoing edge vertices elegantly.

```
{d, e}
```

In other words: I want the children of a vertex only.

The obvious solution for a tree is to always drop the first vertex. Sadly this approach fails for the root vertex, so there has to be some `If`-branching - which I want to avoid.

So far I tried `VertexOutComponent` and `IncidenceList` but non of them seems to give the option to filter by edge direction.

Do you see an elegant approach there, or will I have to keep using root checks?

Comment: With `g = Graph[{a -> b, a -> c, b -> d, b -> e}];` you can do `Last /@ EdgeList[g, b \[DirectedEdge] _]`.

Comment: What did you try with `VertexOutComponent`?  "but non of them seems to give the option to filter by edge direction" $\leftarrow$ actually it does, that's why it has "Out" in the name.

Comment: @Szabolcs I find this whole implementation really confusing.  Why doesn't an `AdjacencyList` for a directed graph include only vertices that are adjacent to the vertex, not also those it is adjacent from.  Wouldn't that be more standard?  (E.g., http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/adjacencyListRep.html)  Somewhat similarly for the `VertexOutComponent`: why does the result for a vertex include that vertex when there is no self loop?  Is there a standard reference that justifies this vocabulary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`VertexOutComponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexOutComponent.html) gives

```
VertexOutComponent[g, b, 1]
(* {b, d, e} *)
```

This is precisely what you are looking for, plus the vertex `b` itself.

---

To retrieve the full adjacency list of a directed graph, you can also use `IGAdjacencyList` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

```
g = Graph[{a -> b, a -> c, b -> d, b -> e}];

IGAdjacencyList[g, "Out"]
(* <|a -> {b, c}, b -> {d, e}, c -> {}, d -> {}, e -> {}|> *)

IGAdjacencyList[g, "In"]
(* <|a -> {}, b -> {a}, c -> {a}, d -> {b}, e -> {b}|> *)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. What confused me is that the vertex itself is included - as in my understanding its not exactly an out component. What I use now is `Drop[VertexOutComponent[g, b, 1], 1]`. This truly returns all vertices from out directed edges of `b`.

Comment: Aren't those duplicates? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97044/graph-subtree-with-respect-to-the-flow