# Vertex descendants subgraph

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks

**Keywords**: vertex, ancestors, descendants, subgraph, directed graph, flow subtree

---

So let's say we have a `TreeGraph`:

```
opts = Sequence[
   EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData["FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.02], 
   VertexLabels      -> "Name"
];

data = RandomInteger[#] -> # + 1 & /@ Range[0, 10];

g = TreeGraph[data, opts]
```

[image]

#### Question

What's the proper/functional way to get subgraph containing only successors of given node with respect to the flow.

I'm not very familiar with graphs so I have a solution (bottom) but I suppose I'm missing some basic graph related functions.

#### Example

for `0` it would be the whole graph

for `4` it would be `{4->5, 5->8, 8->9}`

#### Problem

I can't find appriopriate function and `AdjacencyList/IncidenceList` don't respect the direction of the flow:

```
topV = 4;
HighlightGraph[g, 
  {Style[topV, Blue], AdjacencyList[g, topV, 2], IncidenceList[g, topV, 2]}
]
```

[image]

#### My brute force but not so stupid solution:

**let's cut the inflow! so the AdjacencyList won't leave this way** :)

```
subTreeWF[g, 4] // TreeGraph[#, opts] &
```

[image]

I'm assuming here that the topNode is not the final one, in such case additional check is needed.

```
subTreeWF[treeGraph_, topNode_] := Module[{edges},
  edges = EdgeList @ treeGraph;
  edges = DeleteCases[  edges, 
     (Rule | DirectedEdge | UndirectedEdge)[_, topNode]
  ];
  
  IncidenceList[Graph @ edges, topNode, \[Infinity]]
  
]
```

---

```
g = Graph[RandomInteger[#] -> # + 1 & /@ Range[0, 30], opts];

topV = 5;

HighlightGraph[g, {Style[topV, Blue], subTreeWF[g, topV]}]
```

[image]

Comment: In return for the answer, will you [please test my package](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24709604#24709604), to make sure I didn't mess anything up before I release it? :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok, will try some things ;) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for `VertexOutComponent`.

```
VertexOutComponent[g, 4]
```

gives you the successors of `4`.  Use `Subgraph` to get an actual graph out of those. With `HighlightGraph`, you can also use a subgraph, it will highlight both vertices and edges: `HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, VertexOutComponent[g, 4]]]`.

For visualizing the graph, use `GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`, which will place the root at the topmost position.  Some other tree layouts have a `"RootVertex"` suboptions to achieve this (e.g. for undirected where anything can be the "root").

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, I don't understand your question ...

Comment: @Kuba Ah, I already got a confirmation in chat that it worked fine on Windows, so no need anymore :-)  At least not until the next release

Answer (score 5):

You could also do for example the following for recovering the result as a graph:

```
HighlightGraph[g, s = Last@Reap@BreadthFirstScan[g, 3, {"FrontierEdge" -> Sow}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graph@@s
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]