# Acyclic Directed Graph, NeighborhoodGraph and ancestors

Tags: graphs-and-networks

What is the correct way of find the list of a given vertex' ancestors in an ADG ? I am thinking that a pattern in NeighborhoodGraph might be the solution or a negative option for the degree of neighbourhood but the pattern seems to apply only to the vertex name itself and not the edge.

Thanks and best

Trad.

Comment: Is `VertexInComponent` the answer?

Comment: Hi Kuba, yes indeed. I am not overly familiar with the Graph naming conventions. That should do the trick. I was hoping to find directly the subgraph though. Can I mark your answer up ?

Comment: What do you mean by "find subgraph"? You can do `Subgraph[g, VertexInComponent[g, {3}]]`. p.s. here's closely related topic: [Graph subtree with respect to the flow](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97044/5478) (maybe good enough to be a duplicte), as you can see, I'm not an expert either :)

Comment: You're being modest: from where I stand the question was full of insight. Upmarked as it is spot on what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Great ;) I've voted to mark it as a duplicate since it is the asnwer, don't delete this topic it will stay as a road sign for future visitors.

Comment: Ok. Indeed, it could help other Gephi users in particular, where "ancestor" is the related concept.