# Directed graph, immediate predecessor of a vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In a directed graph, how do you determine all incoming neighbors of a vertex? For the graph {1 -> 2, 0 -> 2, 2 ->3} the incoming neighbors of 2 should 1 and 0. I checked out AdjacencyList. This works for directed graphs but ignores the direction of the edges of adjacent elements.

Note: I checked out Neighborhoodgraph. But, again, for a directed graph it gives neighbors in both directions. I need only the incoming ones.

Comment: Try `VertexInComponent[{1 -> 2, 0 -> 2, 2 ->3},2,1]` (the last `1` stands for the neighborhood of radius 1 (in graph distance)).

Comment: Good enough for a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71566/5478?

Comment: With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), try `IGAdjacencyList[graph, "In"]`